# How to test whether Windows 10 was installed with UEFI?

Tags: uefi, windows-10

I need to decide whether it is more straightforward to create a bootable Ubuntu drive in UEFI or standard BIOS. I do not want to create or install it through any more ambiguous route than necessary because I have experience with accidentally installing one on the other's environment.

Comment: You either boot to the media in UEFI more or you don't.  If there is a EFI partition on the disk that is a good indication.  The title does not really match the body of your question.

Comment: How do I access UEFI mode booting from Windows 10? And is this specific to Ubuntu's boot disk or is this universally UEFI?

Comment: If you installed Windows 10 on a GPT partition then you will be booting in UEFI mode.  What does your question have to do with a Ubuntu?

Comment: UEFI-booting from within Windows 10. I know there is a specific way to make the next reboot pick up installation media in UEFI mode. Bad phrasing on my part in my last comment.

Comment: So you want to access your UEFI firmware menu? [You do so exactly how you did it in Windows 8.x.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html)  Fix your phrasing...You keep calling it "UEFI mode" which isn't really a thing.

Comment: Right, I only called it that after you first called it that actually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open the System Information Utility (Win Key + "R" > "msinfo32" > OK)

In system summary, look for "BIOS MODE".

---

Alternatively, check Disk manager.  If you have a partition on your disk for "EFI system partition" then you are using UEFI.  If you only have system reserved and C:, its probably BIOS.

---

Hope one of these helps

Comment: is it only for win10? I can't see this in Win7

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Windows Panther directory logs:

```
type C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log|find /i "Detected boot environment"
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/04/windows-uefi-o-legacy-bios.html

Comment: My Windows 10 Version 1903 does not have this file: **C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log**

Answer (score 0):

Open the file C:/Windwos/Panther/setupact.log (.log is maybe hidden)

Then search for (Strg+F) ***Detected boot environment:***

If you find

> Detected boot environment: BIOS

then its BIOS, if you find

> Detected boot environment: EFI

then its UEFI.